# How to set logging level in java?

Tags: java, logging

At the moment this is how I'm handling logging:

```
  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger( ClassName.class.getName() );

  log.log( Level.FINE, "processing {0} entries in loop", list.size() );
```

But how do i set the log level? I dont want to do this in each class??

Comment: That completely depends on which logging framework you're using.  See the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

each log have a level :

```
log.debug(processing {0} entries in loop", list.size() ); or /log.info ...
```

and in your confuguration file (log4j.properties) you have a level to display in file
if in  lof4j.properties you have level=WARn then your log.debug and log.info are not display (for production environnement)

You can use annotation with **SLF4j and lombok** to reduce code

```
@Slf4j
public class Test{
   public Test(){
      log.info("constructor");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I see you are using 'Level.FINE' I assume you are using java.util.logging.

The [LogManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) class level documentation describes this in detail.  You can also use [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) to [modify](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LoggingMXBean.html) the logging level.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the framework you are using.

If you are using Log4j framework you can specify the logging levels for specific packages or classes. This can be done either through a properties file, xml configuration, or through code.

Take a look at the documentation, http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html, for specific examples.